# How can I download YouTube videos with their description?

Tags: video, download, automation, youtube, youtube-dl

I'd like to download some Youtube videos to keep them for later, but sometimes the video description is very important, so I want to download the description along with the video.

I can't do that manually because I have a lot of videos, and that would take a lot of time.

How can I do that?

Comment: Next time asking a question, please show what you have already attempted. Also add some info about your operating system.

Comment: @slhck ok i will keep it in mind !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) with the `--write-description` option:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ --write-description
```

That will write both the video and a file with the suffix `.description`.

Comment: thanks so match mate that worked just perfect !
what's the command to do that on playlists too ?

Comment: Just exchange the URL of the video to one of the playlists. Read the documentation of youtube-dl to find out more.

Comment: thank you again :)